Getting an error while deploying my react project in vercel
Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
Cloning github.com/KaungKhantSoe2004/LinWorkOut (Branch: master, Commit: e584ed4)
Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
Cloning completed: 656.11ms
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 34.2.2
Running "install" command: `npm install`...
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated domexception@2.0.1: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
added 1575 packages, and audited 1576 packages in 32s
257 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
12 vulnerabilities (5 moderate, 7 high)
To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix
To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
Run `npm audit` for details.
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.5.0 -> 10.8.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.8.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.8.0` to update!
npm notice 
> lin_work_out@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without
declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your
node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time.
babel-preset-react-app is part of the create-react-app project, which
is not maintianed anymore. It is thus unlikely that this bug will
ever be fixed. Add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" to
your devDependencies to work around this error. This will make this message
go away.
  
Failed to compile.
static/css/main.c0a00a2e.css from Css Minimizer plugin
Error: Unexpected '/'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

I want to deploy project

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
